# Apache Flink issue when defining a StreamTableEnvironment object

Tags: java, docker, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm coding a Java project to create a table within a Dockerized MySQL database using the Apache Flink API. As provided by the doc, I coded the following lines of code in order to define a streaming environment:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env); //<== runtime error
```

After typed **docker-compose build** and **docker-compose up**, the script hangs in a couple of seconds for this reason:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Could not instantiate the executor. Make sure a planner module is on the classpath

and after tens of rows, the runtime error is primarly driven by:

> app_1 | Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in the classpath.

as if the program was unable to link the proper dependency or something like that. The pom.xml file I've used is provided below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-stream</artifactId>
    <version>maven-project</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    

  <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.25</version>
       </dependency>
       
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
       
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
       </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>  
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
          <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
          <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
  </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>single</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                  
                       <archive>
                           <manifest>
                                 <mainClass>com.example.first_stream.WindowWordCount</mainClass>
                           </manifest>
                       </archive>
                       <descriptorRefs>
                           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                      </descriptorRefs>
                 </configuration>
                 
         </plugin>
   </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

while Java code is the following:

```java
package com.example.first_stream;

import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.JdbcConnectionOptions;
import org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.JdbcExecutionOptions;
import org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.JdbcSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.EnvironmentSettings;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor;

public class WindowWordCount {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
        env.execute();          
    }   
}
```

After many attempts I haven't identified the reason why it crashes, neither from the doc nor double-checking the Maven pom.xml. Any idea on how to deal with this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml with us. Which Flink version are you using? The planner is part of the dist but can also be included in the project itself. In any case the versions need to match.

Comment: I'm using Flink 1.14.0 and the planner, defined within the pom.xml `<dependencies>` body, matches that version. I just added the pom.xml file above.

Comment: Maybe it's because some of Flink dependencies should have **provided** scope ?

Comment: I also think that provided scope should be enough. If not, make sure that `META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.Factory` is filled in the JAR file registering the planner as Java Service Loader service. There exists a Maven transformer plugin for merging service files.

Comment: I also tried to set my Flink dependencies **provided** but the situation degrades as the program hangs at the very first line, when setting up the Stream Execution Environment, even before than defining the Stream Table: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment`. @twalthr, I'm sorry but I did't get the point. Am I supposed to import/modify something within the pom.xml to do what you've suggested?

Comment: **EDIT**: I set **provided** only Flink Core dependencies and the StreamExecutionEnvironment definition doesn't fail anymore. I also checked within the `META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.Factory` path and the resource there exists. However, I'm still stuck while trying to define the StreamTableEnvironment for the same reason previously explained. I've added the Java code for a better understanding.

Comment: You are using different Scala versions in your dependencies. `_2.12` should be used consistently. Please replace `flink-table-planner_2.11` and others.

Comment: hi @Simone . have you solved this ? i have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Use this dependency：

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace your dependency：

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add flink-table-planner library in your classpath.